# Choose a value from a column and get the other values relative to the selected value in php

Tags: php, mysql

i inserted various ink names with quantity and total prize to a table that required to print posters (A). And i need to get a summery output table (B). I am design a web system from PHP language. Tried "Distinct" method in SQL but couldn't get. 
(picture attached)
[image: Image here]

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't post images of source code, data or error messages. They are hard to read and can't be easily copied to an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Group By

```
SELECT  ink, sum(qty) as qty,sum(prize) as Total  from tablea group by ink;
```

Comment: Yeah i wanted a guideline how to achieve the output actually. you provided with the code. Thank you. This did the work